# Arithmetic Operation: Int to Double

Tags: c#

I am using 2 textboxes and a button in my Windows application.

`textBox1` is for user input

`textBox2` displays the result of the arithmetic operation.

When the user clicks a button, the following operation should be performed:

```
1000 * textbox1.text / 60
```

For this i used

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Result = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) / 60;

    textBox2.Text = Result.ToString();
}
```

The value I'm getting, however, is an integer, even when I'd expect it to be a double.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please give sample input and what output you want. (We don't have any context here.)

Comment: You even wrote `int Result`, how could you expect *that* to be a `double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forcing the result to be an integer all the way :

```
int Result = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) / 60;
```

You should force Result to be a Double, and force both operands to be doubles :

```
 double Result = 1000 * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) / 60d;
```

(60d stands for (double) 60 - I prefer using type suffixes instead of casts, but it is the same)

Answer (score 8):

The rule is:

> When one integer is divided by another, the arithmetic is performed as
>   integer arithmetic. If you want it to be performed as float, double or
>   decimal arithmetic, you need to cast one of the values appropriately.

So all of these will work:

```
double Result = 1000 * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) / 60;
double Result = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) / (double)60;
double Result = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) / 60.0;
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzydt0tx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) about integer division:

> The result is the integer quotient of number1 divided by number2. The
>   integer quotient discards any remainder and retains only the integer
>   portion.

Answer (score 3):

You should have at least 1 double on the right side

```
double Result = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) / 60.0;
```

Additional note: in order to have a double as a result of an operation like this one, you must give it at least one double, else the right part (`1000 * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) / 60`) will just be an integer, THEN converted to a double by the implicit cast from the left part (`double Result =`).